Error in building project with Anchor
Hello and thanks for your help in advance!
I am having an issue building my project, here is the background:
Fedora Linux v.39
rustc 1.78.0
solana-cli 1.18.24 (src:6b04e881; feat:3241752014, client:Agave)
avm 0.30.1
anchor-cli 0.30.1
Here is the backtrace and build error message....
solana-build-bpf --manifest-path=./programs/blocklockcore/Cargo.toml --bpf-out-dir=./target/deploy
-bash: solana-build-bpf: command not found
[root@Web BlockLockCore]# RUST_BACKTRACE=1 anchor build
thread 'main' panicked at cli/src/lib.rs:545:18:
called Option::unwrap() on a None value
stack backtrace:
0: rust_begin_unwind
1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
2: core::panicking::panic
3: core::option::unwrap_failed
4: anchor_cli::override_toolchain::parse_version
5: anchor_cli::override_toolchain::override_solana_version
6: anchor::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full for a verbose backtrace.
anchor clean
anchor build
error: no such command: +solana
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?


Has anyone dealt with this error before:
"error: no such command: +solana"
Thanks again!

There was probably an issue adding Solana to the correct PATH when you installed it.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965007/solana-command-not-found-after-ubuntu-update-22-04-jammy
or
Solana CLI not updating PATH, new terminal window not recognizing Solana CLI

Hey thanks very much for your response. I tried that, here is the content of my file ~/.bashrc... "export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin
. "$HOME/.cargo/env"
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl-1.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH="/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
" It seems to be an issue with how the toolchain is being specified in the project. I created a file "rust-toolchain" with the contents of "1.81.0" but I have the same error.
